# Why doesn't this command work like I expect?

Tags: bash, quoting, command-substitution

```
cat $(echo this\\ list)
```

Seems like it should be the same as

```
cat this\ list
```

but it isn't.

I know that I can use

```
cat "$(echo this\\ list)"
```

but then I can't echo multiple files into cat.

Why doesn't the first command work?

Comment: ...what are you trying to accomplish?  Also don't use backticks, use `$( ... )` command substitution instead.

Comment: You are obviously trying to solve some sort of problem, but you are going about it in a very odd way.  [Edit] your question to describe the actual problem or situation.

Comment: I don't have a practical use for it, I'm just looking for an explanation as to why it works this way. I'll edit my post to remove the backticks

Comment: Do you have a file in your `PWD` with the filename `./this\ list`?

Comment: no, the file is called `this list`

Comment: You say you have no practical use for it, yet you also say "I can't `echo` multiple files". You therefore have the need to `echo` multiple files (or rather, strings). Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: How are you using the command substitution to generate a list of more than one file?  Could you loop through them with `for`?

Comment: "_Why doesn't the first command work?_" It does work. It's trying to `cat` the contents of the two files `this\ ` and `list`. The problem seems to be that this isn't what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens can be seen with `set -x`:

```
:> set -x
:> cat $(echo this\\ list)
++ echo 'this\' list
+ cat 'this\' list

:> cat this\ list
+ cat 'this list'
```

The difference is that `'this\' list` is two arguments i.e. `cat` tries to read a file `this\` and another file `list` but `'this list'` ist just a single argument i.e. a different file name.

You need:

```
:> cat "$(echo this\ list)"
++ echo 'this list'
+ cat 'this list'
```